# Set environment variables to .env

Tags: linux, docker-compose, environment-variables

I want to set environment variables from docker-compose.yml to .env, when will my entrypoint start. What should I do so that the values of the environment variables from docker-compose.yml are entered into the .env when I make a copy .env.example to .env

entrypoint.sh

```
cp .env.example .env
exec "$@"
```

```
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/php-fpm/Dockerfile
    environment:
      APP_ENV: dev
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html
```

I saw this variant, but he didn't work

.env.example

```
APP_ENV={{ getenv "APP_ENV" | quote }}
```